How to speed up the calculation of matrix eigenvalues ​in MAPLE?
I am solving a computer materials science problem in the MAPLE software package. Solving this problem requires calculating the eigenvalues ​​of matrices of sufficiently large sizes (16x16 or more) and further plotting of graphs using these eigenvalues. The elements of these matrices are trigonometric functions of fairly curved angles. I encountered the problem that when the matrix reaches 24x24 or more in size, MAPLE simply freezes and stops producing any results. I am confident in the correctness of my code, because when working with matrices whose dimensions are smaller than 24x24, MAPLE produces correct results. I calculate the eigenvalues ​​of matrices using the eigenvals() function.
I thought that the problem could be solved by reducing the accuracy of the calculations by decreasing the Digits value. However, in this case, the eigenvalues ​​of the matrices began to be output in the form of RootOf(), despite the fact that at the beginning of the entire code I wrote _EnvExplicit := true. This option does not suit me, since MAPLE does not build graphs based on the eigenvalues ​​of matrices output in the RootOf() format. Using the allvalues() function also does not help get rid of RootOf(). Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
